# How to get rid of Particular Software start page in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide

After trying out NServiceBus a long time ago I have been getting Particular Software's startup page in Visual Studio every time I open the project.

This is not the startup page for when I open the application, but for when I open up a particular solution. I've even uninstalled NServiceBus but the page still opens. For the life of me I can't figure out where to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

The code which opens the Particular Software start page resides in the Init.ps script of the NServiceBus NuGet package. This script should only be executed once, either when a new package is added or when an existing package reference is restored.

If the script is executed every time you open Visual Studio, it probably means that the Init.ps script is failing to complete successfully. Open the NuGet Package Manager Console (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager) and see if any errors are reported.